# Encrypt a file using one's complement

Tags: c++, encryption, stream

I have used C++ file streams to encrypt a file. In this, every character read is one's complemented and written into the output file:

```
ifstream input("Normal file");
ofstream output("encrypted file");
char ch;
while (input >> ch)
{
  ch = ~ch;
  output << ch;
}
```

I used the same program to recover **normal file** from **encrypted file**. However, I found that the unencrypted file did not have any blank spaces or return marks. So, I changed the while part to:

```
while (input >> ch)
{
  ch = isspace(ch) ? ch : ~ch;
  output << ch;
}
```

Till the results are not what I expected. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What did you expect? Could you explain about it?

Comment: One major problem is that the input and output operator `>>` and `<<` are basically *text* functions. When you do the bitwise complement some characters may no longer be represented as "text". Use binary files and other functions to read and write the data.

Comment: Maybe you should try `input.get()` to read whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you're reading the file:

```
char ch;
while (input >> ch)
```

By default, the stream extractor skips all whitespace. To get it to stop that, you can do something like:

```
input >> std::noskipws;
```

...*before* you start reading from the stream.